# ggplot2 only plotting axes - not the points

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a CSV file like:

```
date;foo
2016-07-01;0,54
2016-08-01;0,54
2016-09-01;0,50
2016-10-01;0,49
```

but then read into R and plotted

```
foo2 <- read.csv2("here")
ggplot(foo2, aes(x=date, y=foo))
```

The output is empty. I.e. axes are present but no points are plotted.
A regular `plot(foo2$foo)` simply plots the points - what could be wrong here?

Comment: Add a `geom` to the plot

Comment: `ggplot(foo2, aes(x=date, y=foo)) + geom_{FOO}` where `FOO == [point, line, bar, hist, ...]`

Comment: add +geom_point()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add a geom to your plot. If you want a line plot add...

```
ggplot(foo2, aes(x=date, y=foo)) + geom_line()
```

If you want a scatter plot...

```
ggplot(foo2, aes(x=date, y=foo)) + geom_point()
```

You can find more geoms [here](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/#section-layer-geoms).